# Add two selected value together, then display results JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Been trying to get the values from ID tags **totalDiv-totalDiv1** that each display the results from the selected values, then add them together to display the values combined in real time in ID tag **totalall** but I keep getting **NaN**.

[image]

```
<h2>£10 Each</h2>
<select name="iteam1" onChange="calc1()">
    <option value="10">1</option>
    <option value="20">2</option>
    <option value="30">3</option>
    <option value="40">4</option>
    <option value="50">5</option>
</select>

<div id="totalDiv1">&pound;10</div>

<h2>£10 Each</h2>
<select name="iteam" onChange="calc()">
    <option value="10">1</option>
    <option value="20">2</option>
    <option value="30">3</option>
    <option value="40">4</option>
    <option value="50">5</option>
</select>

<div id="totalDiv">&pound;10</div>
<br>
<h2>Total</h2>
<div id="totalall">&pound;0</div>

<script>
function calc() {

var fruitOrVeg = document.getElementsByName("iteam")[0].value;
var total = fruitOrVeg;
   document.getElementById("totalDiv").innerHTML= "£" +(total);
}
</script>

<script>
function calc1() {

var fruitOrVeg = document.getElementsByName("iteam1")[0].value;
var total = fruitOrVeg;
   document.getElementById("totalDiv1").innerHTML= "£" +(total);
}
</script>

<script>
window.onload = function total() {

    var y = document.getElementById("totalDiv").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("totalDiv1").value;
    var x = +y + +z;
    document.getElementById("totalall").innerHTML = "£" + x;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point to take care.
1. Don't mix value and symbol 
2. You are adding symbol in Calc function in div and later tried to combine them both so it obiviously not a number;

http://jsfiddle.net/ga16gt74/

```
<h2>£10 Each</h2>
<select name="iteam1" onChange="calc1()">
    <option value="10">1</option>
    <option value="20">2</option>
    <option value="30">3</option>
    <option value="40">4</option>
    <option value="50">5</option>
</select>

<div id="totalDiv1">&pound;
  <span id="totalDiv1Value">0</span>
</div>

<h2>£10 Each</h2>
<select name="iteam" onChange="calc()">
    <option value="10">1</option>
    <option value="20">2</option>
    <option value="30">3</option>
    <option value="40">4</option>
    <option value="50">5</option>
</select>

<div id="totalDiv">&pound;
  <span id="totalDivValue">0</span>
</div>
<br>
<h2>Total</h2>
<div id="totalall">&pound;0</div>


<script>
function calc() {
    var fruitOrVeg = document.getElementsByName("iteam")[0].value;
    var value = fruitOrVeg;
    document.getElementById("totalDivValue").innerHTML= value;
    total();
}



function calc1() {
    var fruitOrVeg = document.getElementsByName("iteam1")[0].value;
    var value = fruitOrVeg;
    document.getElementById("totalDiv1Value").innerHTML= value;
    total();
}

function total() {

    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalDivValue").innerHTML);
    var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalDiv1Value").innerHTML);
    var x = y+z;
    document.getElementById("totalall").innerHTML = "£" + x;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var fruitOrEgg = parseInt(documentgetElementsByName("iteam")[0].value);
```

In your calculator function.